# Password protected zip file with Apache ant tag <zipFiles>?

Tags: build, ant, rtc

How to create a password protected ZIP file with RTC Ant build script? Currently my Ant script was able to zip the out files and it is available in RTC download artifacts tab as a Zip file. Some how want to know if it is possible to create 
password projected zip file with ANT scripting.

```
<zipFiles>
   <content>
     <zipfileset>
      .
      .
     </zipfileset>
   </content>
</zipFiles>
```

Comment: Ant does not support password-protected archives. You will have to use an external program with the `exec` task.